# validation on radio button with JS confrim dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to disable check event on a radio button. Here is the scanrio.

In a radio group if `button1` is checked, and user clicks on `button2` user will see a JS confirm dialog, if user clicks on **OK** `button2` will be checked and if user clicks on **Cancel** the previously checked button `Button1` will remain checked.

Here is what I have tried.

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" checked="true" name="radioName" onclick="setData(this)" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" onclick="setData(this)"  value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" onclick="setData(this)"  value="3" /> 3 <br />
</form>

function setData(ctrl)
{
  var r = confirm("The selected option contains data, unchecking this option will delete this data. Do you want to continue ?");
      if (r == true) {
      // clicked Radio button gets checked
      } else {
      // perviously checked button remains checked
       return false;
      }
  }
```

but I am unable to achieve desired results.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RhnvU/5547/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is correct, except in your onclick handler you should call the function with `return` since you will be returning false incase of user-pressed-cancel.

Try something like this -

```
onclick="return setData(this)"
```

Here is the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/RhnvU/5550/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function setData(ctrl) {
  var r = confirm("continue?");

  if (r == true) {
    // clicked Radio button gets checked
  } else {
    // perviously checked button remains checked
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `event` defined ? You forgot to pass it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was not aware this property is non-standard. https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Comment: @Yasser that is globally available if initialized with any event. but if you pass then you have to use that instead and that is actually better one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of `.click()`, use `onmousedown` event. This is because it will make a decision before changing the value of the radio button, instead of making decision after the value has already been set by the `click`.

So the HTML code becomes:

```
<input type="radio" checked="true" name="radioName" onmousedown="setData(this)" value="1" />
```

and in the Js file, simply use `.checked` property based on the value of selection:

```
if (r == true) {
        ctrl.checked = true;
      // clicked Radio button gets checked
      } else {

       return false;
      }
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ht8duy9h/)

**Detailed explanation:**
What it will do is the following:

1. When you will click on a radio button, it will fire the onmousedown event.
2. onmousedown event handler will check whether you have clicked "Ok" or "cancel".
3. If it is "ok", it will check the new value of radio button.
4. If it is "cancel", it will do nothing,so the old value of radio button remains still.

Answer (score 0):

```
'e.keycode == 32' is used to trigger the same event in case of space key press. Hope this helps.   

 $('.button1').on('click keyup' , function(e){
                    if(e.keyCode == 32 || e.type=="click"){
                        //show your Dialog or pop-up
                        $('.popup').show();
                        $('#proceed').click(function(){
                            selectradioButton1();
                        });
                        $('#cancel').click(function(){
                            $('.popup').hide();
                        });
                    }
                });
    $('.button2').on('click keyup' , function(e){
                    if(e.keyCode == 32 || e.type=="click"){
                        selectradioButton2();
                    }
                });

    function selectradioButton1() {
        $('#radiobtn1').attr('checked', true);
        $('#radiobtn2').attr('checked', false);
    }

    function selectradioButton1() {
        $('#radiobtn2').attr('checked', true);
        $('#radiobtn1').attr('checked', false);
    }
```